# ConcurrentModificationExample and possible code simplification

Tags: java, linked-list

I am throwing a ConcurrentModificationExample in the following code.  I checked the API and it has to do with me trying to modify an object while another thread is iterating over it.  I am clueless on the matter.  I have created a comment above the line causing the exception.  The Employee class doesn't contain anything other than the three variables for storing information.

I will be including the entire class as I would also like to know if there is a way to simplify my code as it repeats many things such as object creation and adding everything to the lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call employeesByAge in here with dep.employees:

```
dep.employeesByAge(dep.employees)
```

that will pass in dep.employees to employeesByAge such that in:

```
public class Department{
    LinkedList<Employee> employees = ...;
    public LinkedList<Employee> employeesByAge(LinkedList<Employee> outputList) {
        ...
    }
}
```

both the employee member field and the outputList parameter refers to the same list, not just two list with the same content, but the same list instance.

Then you do:

```
for (Employee emp: employees){
    //the list is null. add the first employee

    if (outputList.isEmpty()){
        outputList.add(emp);
    } else
    ...
}
```

which iterates the employee and modifies outputList, but remember that these two are the same list object. Thus, ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do is similar to this...

```
List list = ...;
for(item: list) {
    list.add(item);
}
```

That is, you're updating a collection with elements by iterating over the same collection. All

```
outputList.add(...);
```

in Department are adding elements to the collection from the same collection 'employees'.
In main(), by doing

```
dep.employeesByAge(dep.employees)
```

you're attempting to update 'dep.employees' with 'dep.employees.' which results in concurrent modification exception.

Comment: please forgive my ignorance but i do not see how I am adding the same objects to the same list.  the sorting method creates a new list and returns that.  the for loop then iterates over that new list.